# Visual Studio for mac always requires download Mono framework

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

every time you open a Visual Studio requires download Mono framework, even if it was previously installed.
when I set the framework, the studio normally open, but if I close and reopen it requires more time to establish the same framework

Comment: the same with me but how you solve them 
,note it is my first time to install it in my mac os sierra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that during the the update was run Xamarin Studio.
The problem was solved, just completed all the programs, Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio, and run the installation package manually.

Comment: I have the same problem, but never had installed Xamarin Studio.

Comment: @Weltraumschaf, sorry, but after uninstalling xamarin studio, there were no problems

Comment: I had to delete the Visual Studio.app and install it from scratch. Reinstall without deleting the old one did not worked.